# Re-drawing drawn mapbox GL features

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am developing an application using angular 1.5 and the javascript Mapbox GL library.

I've loaded the https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/ plugin to enable users to draw their own lines and polygons. This works wonderfully.

Now I want the drawn lines to be persistent. So when the user leaves the page and returns the previously drawn lines are re-drawn and can be edited and deleted as you'd expect.

To save the drawn lines I listen for the draw.create event, use the Draw.getAll() to grab all drawn layers and save them somewhere so it's available throughout my application.

*So far so good.*

Now for the persistence part; whenever I re-visit the map's page, I have all the data I need and use the following API call to attempt to re-draw the features.

```
function reDrawRoutes(){
    var id = Draw.add(scope.model.drawn_routes);
}
```

I have also tried the following method (as both should have similar outcomes according to the mapbox-gl-draw docs):

```
function reDrawRoutes(){
    var id = Draw.set(scope.model.drawn_routes);
}
```

FYI; the **scope.model.drawn_routes** contains an array of objects like this:

```
Array[1]
    0: Object
        geometry: Object
            coordinates: Array[2]
            type: "LineString"
        id: "23f7fd3af36d6ba6ea02907b10f40391"
        properties: Object
            type: "Feature"
```

Now for the strange part;

Whenever I call the above method, no apparent changes are made. However! When I press the "draw line" or "draw polygon" buttons the routes are actually drawn on the map!

So there is something going on I'm missing. I dug a bit deeper and called the Draw.getAll() right after I called the Draw.set()/add() method and I see my added feature like you'd expect.

But when I called the Draw.getAll() method right after the draw.mode_changed (which fires after i click the draw line/polygon buttons) event fires I see that there's suddenly an extra feature. So clicking the buttons actually creates the lines I want to draw.

Draw.getAll() results after calling Draw.set(scope.model.drawn_routes):

```
Object
    type: "FeatureCollection"
    features: Array[1]
        0: Object
            type: "Feature"
            geometry: Object
                coordinates: Array[2]
                type: "LineString"
            id: "b89da95478ca83d653cf9756a1531f0b"
            properties: Object
                // empty object
```

Draw.getAll() results after clicking either the draw line or draw polygon button:

```
Object
    type: "FeatureCollection"
    features: Array[2]
        0: Object
            type: "Feature"
            geometry: Object
                coordinates: Array[2]
                type: "LineString"
            id: "b89da95478ca83d653cf9756a1531f0b"
            properties: Object
                // empty object

        1: Object
            type: "Feature"
            geometry: Object
                coordinates: Array[0]
                type: "LineString"
            id: "79cad278991d533454612e2b783f5abe"
            properties: Object
                // empty object
```

So as you can see the second feature that shows up after click the draw controls doesn't even have coordinates.

So my question is: **what is going on here? How can I re-draw the routes I've extracted and saved?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick,

The problem you are having is because you are calling `Draw.set()` before the all the assets needs to render the map have been loaded. To fix this, make sure you are initializing Draw inside of the `map.on('load', function() { ... });` callback. People often get `load` and `style.load` confused. `load` is the event you need to listen for.

Comment: Bit late, but thanks for the response! That turned out to be the problem.